# Ошибка с аргументом self

Tags: python

```
class LinkToParty(disnake.ui.View):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.add_item(disnake.ui.Button(label="Join to us!", url = ' '))
```

Command raised an exception: TypeError: View.to_components() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Comment: Приведите полный текст ошибки

Comment: @andreymal Добрый день, я привел полный текст ошибки :/

Comment: Он не полный, значит кто-то в вашем коде обрезает полный текст ошибки

Comment: Почему-то кажется, что ошибка происходит при непрерывном обращении к экземпляру этого класса и представленный фрагмент здесь не при чем